# Append to a file in JavaIoFileSystemAccess

Tags: java, filesystems

How do I append text to a file in JavaIoFileSystemAccess?

I have tried calling the generateFile with the same filename, but it just overwrites the content of the file.

Is there a setting or method I can call to be able to append contents to a file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FileWriter` `class` overloaded constructor for this.

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("filepath in string"),true);  

//second parameter specifies whether write this file
                                              in append mode or normal mode  
//true for append mode
```